# Does midpoint convexity at a single point imply full convexity at that point?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convex-analysis

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb [0,\infty)$ be a continuous function, and let $c \in (a,b)$ be a **fixed** point.

Suppose that $f$ is midpoint-convex at the point $c$, i.e.

$$
f((x+y)/2) \le (f(x) + f(y))/2,
$$
whenever $(x+y)/2=c$, $x,y \in [a,b]$.

> Is it true that $f$ is convex at $c$? i.e. does
> $$
> f\left(\alpha x + (1- \alpha)y \right) \leq \alpha f(x) + (1-\alpha)f(y)
> $$
> hold whenever $ \alpha \in [0,1]$ and $x,y \in [a,b]$ satisfy $\alpha x + (1- \alpha)y =c$?

Does the answer change if we assume $f$ is strictly decreasing?

The [classic](https://mathoverflow.net/a/347499/46290) proofs do not seem to adapt to this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick $c=0$ and $f: [-1,1] \rightarrow [0,\infty), f(x)=-x^3+1$. Then we have for $c=0$ that $x=-y$.
$$ f(0)=1 = (-x^3 +1 +-(-x)^3+1)/2 = (f(x)+f(y))/2. $$
So $f$ is midpoint-convex. However, for $\alpha=2/3$ and $x=-1/2, y=1$ we have
$$ \alpha x + (1-\alpha) y= \frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{-1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} \cdot 1 = 0 = c $$
and
$$ \alpha f(x) + (1-\alpha) f(y) = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{9}{8} + \frac{1}{3} \cdot 0  = \frac{3}{4} < 1 = f(0). $$
So our function is not convex at $c=0$ (and $f$ is even strictly decreasing).

Comment: Thank you. In the last line I think you should remove the $1/2$, right? (so the final number is $\frac{3}{4}$). By the way, I guess you chose $1-x^3$ instead of $-x^3$ just in order to get a nonnegative $f$, as stated in the question, right?

Comment: Indeed, I just added the $1$ to make it nonnegative. Also, of course you are right about the factor of $2$. The idea was to take some odd function to get midpoint-convexity and then I saw that you want it to be nonnegative, so I added a constant. So you can take your favorite continuous, odd function which is not convex at the origin (adding a constant to make it nonnegative if you like and shifting if you dislike the origin).